# Form with one to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, foreign-keys

In my database I have 2 tables:

**Course** table:

- id (PK)
- name (varchar)
- description (text)

**Session** table:

- id (PK)
- date (datetime)
- course_id (FK to id from course table)

The *buildForm* function in my **SessionType** looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('date');
}
```

The *buildForm* function in my **CourseType** looks like this:

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('description')
    ->add('foreknowledge')
    ->add('teacher')
    ->add('sessions', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => SessionType::class,
        'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'allow_delete' => true,
    ))
```

My form in my twig template looks like this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

But nothing is shown under "Sessions". I would like to have the possibility to create multiple sessions under my course. Is there an easy way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

When I try to save my course and do a dump just before I save I get this:

[image]

My sessions are saved, but they are not linked to course. How does this come?

[image]

Comment: I guess you mean "ManyToMany" relation, cause the "OneToMany" is not logic (your db design) in this case: each session can have many courses, and each course can existed at many sessions

Answer (score 1):

That is possible and you are missing some javascript, it is very well documented [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype).

Instead of copy-pasting from that documentation page here, you can read it and ask if you need any help with it.

Comment: @nielsv in your Course Entity you have addSession method? And you forward session var? in that method do `$session->setCourse($this)` and that should resolve it